# Digital camera with WI-FI and time-lapse function

Tags: timelapse, wireless

Is there any digital camera, that can be controled remotely and upload images automaticly to ftp (something like Eye-fi) over internet and have ability to take pictures in time sequence every minute (time lapse function ?).

I found wi-fi enabled cameras from Samsung (HS-100) and Cannon IXUS cameras. IXUS are good, but there is no time-lapse function. If there will be CHDK, that will be great, but wi-fi enabled cameras don´t have this firmware update.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but couldn't you use an Eye-Fi card in a camera that does time lapse?

Comment: With Eye-Fi, camera cant be controlled remotely.. only sending images to desired location. But I need change interval of time-lapse or something else over network.

Comment: What camera do you have already?  And what quality of photos for you want/need.  It might be cheaper to point out "upgrade" options instead of trying to find an entirely new rig.  (On a pro Nikon you could hook a MC-22 to a small computer like an Arduino for a few hundred bucks.) ... then again a $15 webcam and a laptop could be used if you just need low res shots.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** *Ironically, while I wrote this answer, the press release of the first camera to do this was waiting in my inbox* :)

**There is one such camera**, it is the [Panasonic Lumix GH3](http://www.neocamera.com/camera/panasonic/gh3).

A few [WiFi cameras exist](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php?wifi=1)  without this function but do not despair. Once cameras have WiFi control, **such functions can be software driven** and do *not* have to be built into the camera.

What you need to do is **look at software to control WiFi cameras**, you can probably code your own if you were so inclined and I am sure others will eventually do it for popular models. I would look at what Panasonic has to offer for the [SZ5](http://www.neocamera.com/camera/panasonic/sz5), as I've seen some impressive demos. Once the [Canon EOS 6D](http://www.neocamera.com/camera/canon/6d) ships, I fully expect plenty of developments in the area too, since it is the first DSLR with built-in WiFi.

Answer (score 3):

Smartphones these days have on average 8 mega pixel sensors, autofocus and other decent camera features, as well as having WiFi built in.

I'm sure there are probably apps available that allow precise control of the hardware. If not, consider commissioning one; it's not as expensive as some of the more costly camera accessories and you could sell it to other users later to recoup the investment.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard from a friend that owns one that GoPro cameras are good at doing time-lapse, and it seems you can use an [accessory](http://gopro.com/hd-hero-accessories/wi-fi-bacpac-remote-combo/) to control it over Wifi (although it's not cheap...).

Answer (score 1):

Canon just announced the S110 compact with WiFi. Too new to have a price yet. Preview on http://www.dpreview.com/previews/canon-powershot-s110/

Comment: It's $449 USD but does not have time-lapse or remote control features, so it won't cut it for this use.

Comment: Now $399 on Amazon. And as a Canon it's theoretically CHDK-compatible, which includes great timelapse capability.

Answer (score 0):

Any of the new cameras (like the first set from [Samsung and Nikon](http://www.networkworld.com/community/blog/nikon-and-samsung-create-new-camera-category-embedding-android)) which include the [Android operating system](https://android.stackexchange.com/) should do this. They have wifi, and you could run one of the existing Android timelapse apps (or write your own if you have custom needs).

If your image quality needs aren't great, you could simply use any smartphone to accomplish the same thing. (iOS or Android; they both have the necessary software. Presumably Windows as well but I don't know.)

Answer (score 0):

Coming from a Nerdy background myself, I would suggest:

- Any DSLR, as an example, a Canon.
- Plugged to a computer, eg a netbook.
- Running the EOS Utility plugged to camera with a cable.

And then, you can connect remotely from another computer to the netbook plugged to the camera using something like logmein.com to change the settings on EOS Utility.

You can configure EOS Utility to copy the photos to a directory that is controlled by dropbox, to send the images back to you.